# To reset iPhone passcode after maximum number of failed attempts

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mdm, passcode

Is it possible to reset the iPhone passcode after user has exceeded maximum number of failed attempts on his iPhone which is registered to MDM server by using the app(programmatically) with which it is registered or send the information to MDM administrator that certain device is locked. Or must the device be connected to its designated iTunes in order to be unlocked. Please help! I have googled it but found nothing. Can we restrict the attempts to reach its maximum value.